# creating new sigma algebras from old sigma algebras

Tags: real-analysis

Let $\mathscr{A}$ be sigma-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and let $B \in \mathscr{A} $. Put

$$ \mathscr{F} = \{ A \cap B : A \in \mathscr{A} \} $$

Then, $\mathscr{F}$ is a sigma-algebra of subsets of $B$. Is this still holds if we dont require $B $ to be in $\mathscr{A} $ ?

$Attempt$:

we have $\varnothing = \varnothing \cap A \in \mathscr{F} $ and $B = B \cap B \in \mathscr{ F}$. Next, suppose $A_n \in \mathscr{F}$ for all $n=1,2,... $, so $A_n \subset B  $ for all $n$. Hence, $\bigcup_n A_n \in \mathscr{A}$. It follows that $\bigcup A_n \in \mathscr{F}$. Similarly, $\bigcap A_n \in \mathscr{F}$.

For the second question, i say the asnwer is no. Let $\Omega =\{1,2\} $ and let $\mathscr{A} = \{ \varnothing, \Omega \} $. Let $B = \{1 \} $. Then, $\mathscr{F} = \{ B \cap A : A \in \mathscr{A} \} $ is not a sigma algebra of subsets of $B$ since $B = \{1\} \notin \mathscr{F}$.

Is this a correct approach?

Comment: Isn't {1} the intersection of {1} and {1,2}?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed it is a sigma-algebra on B, even if B does not belong to the original sigma-field. The proof is really routine, just checking the 3 axioms of a sigma-field.